# .htaccess trailing slashes and ajax calls

Tags: htaccess

I'm building something with Craft and Vue.js and realized that I could view my page with or without a trailing slash, but when it had a trailing slash, my ajax calls to the Element API endpoint failed, thus the content wouldn't load.  So I've changed all my endpoints to not include the `.json` like in the plugin's docs examples and just end in a `/`.

I'm not sure if it's better or worse to force a trailing slash (I've read arguments for either way online), but I figure it's best to just choose one and go with it, so I've chosen to force it, but then I can't log into my admin control panel anymore, and I get some javascript errors elsewhere on front-end pages.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect non www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # 301 redirect with trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm also adding `'addTrailingSlashesToUrls' => true,` in my config file.

How can I fix this to have trailing slashes, ensure that ajax calls don't fail, and still log into the cms?  Or should I just force no trailing slash?